# Enable custom skill through voice

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am trying to enable skill like ***"Alexa, Enable [custom-skill] Skill"***, but it's not working. The invocation name fit in brand/intellectual property, and I am using avs from same account.

Is there any way to keep enable my custom skill for avs?

Comment: You don't need to enable skills in your own account. They are automatically enabled from the web interface when you create them and you could disable and re-enable them from there.

Comment: Thanks @JosepValls for response, But if i am trying activate skill in other account then it wont.

Answer (score 1):

If your skill has not passed certification you cannot enable it in other accounts unless you setup beta testing. Refer to the official documentation to enable beta testing: https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/skills-beta-testing

Once your skill has passed certification, you can enable by voice or in the Alexa app in any other accounts.

Comment: Hi @Josep, My skill already published and available for all customer, but end user unable to Enable Skill through voice

Comment: If you tell me your skill's name I'll try myself. It should work.

Comment: Skill Name: "shipco"

Comment: Hi @Josep Valls  you have any solution?

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap I tried enabling the skill by voice and it wouldn't understand me. I think you may need to contact Amazon to see if they can offer a solution. They have a forum for developers you may try to use.

Comment: I am trying to contact to amazon since 3 weeks, but didnt get proper response, amazon developer said, i can enable skill through voice, you need to check voice training session(app)